# Почему nginx отображает php файлы как текстовые?

Tags: nginx

У меня в настройках /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default расскоментировал вот эти строки

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php7.0-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
```

И подключил php7.0 php7.0-fpm и все, но у меня код весь отображается как текст, допустим то есть там отображается весь код и ключая var_dump($path) так же отображается. Что примерно я не так еще настроил?
Вот чтобы было понятно что php7.0-fpm работает

```
php7.0-fpm.service - The PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php7.0-fpm.service; enabled; vendor prese
   Active: active (running) since Чт 2018-04-19 08:59:49 MSK; 2h 13min ago
 Main PID: 1044 (php-fpm7.0)
   Status: "Processes active: 0, idle: 2, Requests: 4, slow: 0, Traffic: 0req/se
   CGroup: /system.slice/php7.0-fpm.service
           ├─1044 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf)       
           ├─1047 php-fpm: pool www                                             
           └─1048 php-fpm: pool www                                             

апр 19 08:59:48 ruslan-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M systemd[1]: Starting The PHP 7.0 Fa
апр 19 08:59:49 ruslan-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M systemd[1]: Started The PHP 7.0 Fas
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php7.0-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Отображаю файл /var/www/test.php

```
$path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
        if ($path == '/'){
            $path = '';
        } else {
            $path = preg_replace('/', '', $path);
        }

        var_dump($path);
```

Comment: чисто формально сделано правильно. и есть сто причин, где может быть ошибка. 1) nginx перезапускали? 2) покажите весь конфиг, а не этот кусок 3) в `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` включено "include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;"?

Comment: nginx перезапустил

Comment: конфиг имеетя этого файла /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Comment: Чтобы понимали: обработка начинается с `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. В нем есть `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` который включает все конфиги из этого каталога. А может быть кто-то там уже покопался и сделал по-своему, например `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;`. Nginx только что поставили, или там уже куча всего было? Приложите основной файл и файл под этот сайт. Дальше будем смотреть.

Comment: только установил

Comment: конфиг `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` абсолютно рабочий. Сделайте на сервере: `curl 'http://127.0.0.1:80/test.php'` - что выводит?

Comment: Еще что-то напутано: `root /var/www/html;` а файл в `/var/www/test.php`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76264/discussion-between-total-pusher-and-).

Comment: Да я перепутал забыл что эти файлы находятся в /var/www/html